# jquery event for when <option>s are added or removed from a <select>

Tags: jquery, html, events, onchange

Is there a jquery event for when options are added or removed from a select control on an HTML page? I have tried `.change()` but it only seems to fire when I click on option elements. I.e. this doesn't work:

```
$(function() {
    $('#select').change(function() {
            alert('hello world');
    })
});
```

Thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a plugin to check if there is HTML added or removed from the DOM. livequery is a plugin http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery

Answer (score 2):

When adding a new element to an existing dropdown, you should do a:  $("#selector").trigger ("change");  to get the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the standard `change()` event will do this for you. What you will want to do is have a function that is fired when you add a new option to the select box. How are you currently adding options to this select box?

Comment: Basically this on a click event using the HTML5 data attributes: `var data = $(this).data('shift');`
`$(':selected', $(data.from)).appendTo($(data.to));`

Comment: Good idea.. I will just add some code to the function I am using.. that will work :) + 1