# Select option is added or removed event

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I detect if OPTION is added or removed from SELECT?

I know about this: [jquery event for when <option>s are added or removed from a <select>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124919/jquery-event-for-when-options-are-added-or-removed-from-a-select)

this select boxes are controled by another js that I can't put my own function call in.

Can I detect somehow that option has been removed by another js?

Comment: Do you know *how*  they are added or removed? Is there some abstraction method you can work with?

Comment: They are manipulated by this jquery plugin http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/select/

Comment: But I would not like to hardcode site specific manipulation because i intend to reuse code on other site

Comment: @mgalesic I posted a solution below that avoids polling and unnecessary unresponsiveness/load on the machine. You may want to test that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try calling a checking function for a given select Element, using a timeout to check periodically.

```
function periodicallyCheckSelect(){
      var jSelect = $(this)
         ,opts = this.options 
         ,prevLen = +jSelect.attr('data-previousLen') || opts.length
         ,isEq = false
         ,isAdded = false
         ,isRemoved = false
         ,state = '';
      isEq = opts.length === prevLen;
      isAdded = opts.length > prevLen;
      isRemoved = opts.length < prevLen;
      state =  isEq ? 'no change' 
               : isAdded ? opts.length-prevLen + ' option(s) added' 
               : prevLen-opts.length+' option(s) removed';
      jSelect.attr('data-previousLen',opts.length);
      log(state+'<br>');
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/c8VMh/) playing around with the idea.

Comment: I like this solution. I will check if select box exist on page and if so start checking for changes

Answer (score 0):

Try to look through [Mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events)

Answer (score 0):

How about patching the append function on the element? Example:

```
var obj = document.getElementById('#select');
obj.__appendChild = obj.appendChild;
obj.appendChild = function(){
    console.log('new option added');
    obj.__appendChild.apply(obj, arguments); 
}
```

Comment: @mgalesic Above solution avoids polling and unnecessary unresponsiveness/load on the machine. You may want to test overriding method.